# How to sort an array using values from an enum?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to sort elements of an array using an enum, I would like to know how to do it, I have tried with a `switch` statement with no success.

```
   const enum Order {
      Start = 'Start',
      Run = 'Run',
      End = 'End',
    }

    const predicate (a, b) => // TODO 

    const data = [Order.End, Order.Run, Order.Start]

    const result = data.sort(predicate)

    // wanted result is: // Start, Run, End
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally with an enum, the value is already comparable.

```
const enum Order {
    Start = 0,
    Run = 1,
    End = 2,
}

const data = [Order.End, Order.Run, Order.Start];

const result = data.sort();

console.log(result);
```

A non-constant enum can even be mapped to the string values, as shown here:

```
enum Order {
    Start = 0,
    Run = 1,
    End = 2,
}

const data = [Order.End, Order.Run, Order.Start];

const result = data.sort();

console.log(result.map((val) => Order[val]));
```

But in your case, you could convert them into an easily sortable value if necessary (assuming you desire to avoid alphabetical ordering).

```
const enum Order {
    Start = 'Start',
    Run = 'Run',
    End = 'End',
}

const predicate = (a, b) => {
    const map = {};
    map[Order.Start] = 1;
    map[Order.Run] = 2;
    map[Order.End] = 3;

    if (map[a] < map[b]) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (map[a] > map[b]) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

const data = [Order.End, Order.Run, Order.Start];

const result = data.sort(predicate);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! is it possible to get the ordinal number directly from typescript wit out using the map?

Comment: If you use a non-const enum with numeric values you can access the string names and the value. So the second example where `val` is the value and `Order[val]` is the name. When using a `const enum` every use gets replaced with a literal value, so there isn't anywhere to store another value except in a separate map.

Answer (score 2):

I created a function in typescript based on previous answer to order objects from an enum.

```js
export function sortByStatus(a: Element, b: Element): number {
    const map = new Map<Status, number>();
    map.set(Status.DONE, 0);
    map.set(Status.ERROR, 1);
    map.set(Status.PROCESSING, 2);
    map.set(Status.NONE, 3);

    if (map.get(a.status) < map.get(b.status)) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (map.get(a.status) > map.get(b.status)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Furthermore, I include a mini test to check its functionality.

```js
it('check sortByStatus', () => {
    expect(sortByStatus(a, b)).toBeLessThanOrEqual(1);
    expect(sortByStatus(b, a)).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(-1);
    expect(sortByStatus(a, a)).toBe(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response I used:

```js
const Order = {
  Start:'Start',
  Run: 'Run',
  End: 'End',
}

const orderValues = Object.values(Order)

const predicate = (a, b) =>
  orderValues.findIndex(value => a === value) - orderValues.findIndex(value => b === value)

const data = [Order.End, Order.Run, Order.Start]

const result = data.sort(predicate)

console.log(result)
```